# Application.Run on each iteration

Tags: excel, subroutine, vba

I'm having a strange issue with Application.Run in a subprocedure that adds new rows (1 or more depending on user's choice). I wanted to separate the AddRowsBelow() sub so I can reuse it somewhere else too:

```
Sub AddRowsBelow(Coord As Range, RowsToAdd As Long, Optional SubName As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim newRowNr As Integer: newRowNr = Coord.Row

    For i = 1 To RowsToAdd
        Coord.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert xlDown

        If LenB(SubName) <> 0 Then
            newRowNr = newRowNr + 1
            Application.Run SubName, newRowNr
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

When I pass following sub as an argument, it Debug.Prints rowNr successfuly on each iteration, but the rest of the code only runs once in case of more rows – nothing happens for other iterations. It is run on a range formatted as Excel Table.

```
Sub FlagAsSublist(rowNr As Integer)
    Sheet2.Cells(rowNr, 1).Value = ChrW(sublistFlag)
    Debug.Print rowNr
    Sheet2.Range(Cells(rowNr, 4), Cells(rowNr, 11)).Borders(xlInsideVertical).ColorIndex = 2
End Sub
```

Any ideas why it does not work?

Comment: Is rowNr a public variable? What happens if you delete `Debug.Print rowNr`?

Comment: Why do you use `Application.Run`? Is the `FlagAsSublist` in another WorkBook?

Comment: @Tom, rowNr is passed as an argument via Application.Run 
@ ZwoRmi, I'd like to build my own functions & subs to export and use them again somewhere else, so I'm interested in this particular approach. FlagAsSublist is just another macro in the same workbook.